# Why doesn't date set correctly when using ajax in commandbutton

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2.2

The code below will not set the date1 and date2 when using the commented ajax call in JSF. But it will be set when using an action.

What would be the correct way to set them using ajax?

```
<h:outputText value="Startdatum"></h:outputText>
<p:calendar value="#{calendarBean.date1}" id="popupButtonCal"
    showOn="button" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss">
</p:calendar>
<h:outputText value="Slutdatum"></h:outputText>
<p:calendar value="#{calendarBean.date2}" id="popupButtonCal2"
    showOn="button" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss">
</p:calendar>
<h:outputText value=""></h:outputText>
<h:commandButton value="Visa lista"
    action="#{serviceSeries.getSeriesForPlayerInfo(serviceHCP.myCurrentClub.name, player, serviceSerieType.mySerieType, calendarBean) }">
    <!-- p:ajax update=":form2" render=":form2" listener="#{serviceSeries.getSeriesForPlayerInfo(serviceHCP.myCurrentClub.name, player, serviceSerieType.mySerieType, calendarBean) }" / -->
</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: Set the dates on what? Are you saying the `calendarBean` passed in as an argument to your `listener` hasn't got the updated values or the bean instance is missing them?

Comment: I will set the values in the popout calendar that primefaces supplies. However I am getting the impression that I need to have <f:ajax process="@this" /> to get it to work on all components. Yes the bean instance is missing them.